# Xlib without X11? Any library or system is capable of doing this?

Tags: x11, xorg

First of all, the X protocol can't be fully understood without a server-client architecture, but, however, most XWindow applications use Xlib and Xt in a way that could be encapsulated inside Xlib itself, just translating the framebuffer and mouse/keyboard I/O towards any other API, like SDL for example.

Do you know of any Xlib "frontend" doing this?

Or, alternatively, any "dummy XServer" that could offer the same idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Technically `Xlib` *is* `X11`, although the developers of `xcb` have replaced parts of that with `xcb` (see [Xlib and XCB](http://www.x.org/wiki/guide/xlib-and-xcb/)).  Doing that (to address limitations in the existing `Xlib`) was the purpose of writing `xcb` (see [XCL : An Xlib Compatibility Layer For XCB](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/usenix02/tech/freenix/full_papers/sharp/sharp_html/)).

But no one has combined `Xlib` with `Xt` simply because the design goals differ a lot.  Rather, other toolkits have been built — over `Xlib`.  `SDL` is one of several different toolkits.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, AFAIK, XCB is an implementation of the server-client X protocol. I'm asking for some Xlib implementation (or "Xlib frontend") that doesn't translate function calls into X protocol communication, but instead implement the function call on top of some API that can provide all the framebuffer, keyboard, mouse, I/O that Xlib needs. I mentioned SDL as an example of an API providing most of the functionality that Xlib needs. Regarding Xt, I put it as an example of the functionality that most apps use (I could have put GTK as another example).

Comment: Proving non-existence is probably out of scope for this forum; I clarified the question in the first paragraph, and summarized the reason why it is unlikely in the second paragraph.  To get a better answer, you should limit the question, rather than expand it in comments.

Comment: What I'd like to find is a library with all (or most) of the Xlib functions implemented in a way that it doesn't need an XServer for providing the expected functionality to the application. I don't know how to express it better in my question, I thought I had expressed it accurately.

Comment: Take a look at https://blog.littlevgl.com/2018-01-03/linux_fb maybe.  Also at https://docs.littlevgl.com/  It's a whole widget set and library designed for framebuffer use without X.

Comment: but it's not **Xlib**, and doesn't have either the same API or wire-protocol.